# Can node and nginx use the same cores simultaneously on a dedicated server safely (no docker)?

Tags: node.js, performance, nginx

I have a 16 core 64 gigs of ram dedicated server.

I'm running node / express in pm2 cluster mode and also a nginx reverse proxy on the same server without docker. No other services are running on this server.

Is it safe to run 1 node process per core (16 total) and also set nginx worker_processes to use all 16 cores at the same time? Will node and nginx using the same cores at the same time conflict / cause issues?

Or do I have to set 8 cores for node and 8 cores for nginx?

Comment: I would suggest you look at Systemd slices. Use the slices and set what CPU and RAM % levels you want to allocate to both. Its better to control the CPU/RAM limits that way. https://www.scylladb.com/2019/09/25/isolating-workloads-with-systemd-slices/

Comment: @TarunLalwani interesting, I will look into it. Thanks!